# Proper Network Activation problem has been fixed in wp 3.3.1 or not?

Tags: multisite

@scribu opened a core trac [ticket here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14170) for Proper Network Activation problem in multisite.  It seems like its fixed in wp 3.1.

But [scribu was saying](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-proper-network-activation-why-is-this-functionality-not-in-wordpress-core?replies=8) it doesn't fixed in wp 3.1.

So he released a plugin for [proper network activation](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/proper-network-activation/).

I'm using wordpress multisite. So can anyone tell me whether this problem fixed in wp3.3.1 or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: No, it hasn't been fixed - You should use the plugin instead.

In Detail: Activation hooks should work for the main site properly. For subsites (or as Nacin pointed out: for all sites), you should use a proper upgrade routine. *Not that I double that <sup>1)</sup>.*

<sup>1) Note to myself: When a core dev says that core internals are *lame*, then this should tell me something. Not shure what exactly, but I'll think about it.</sup>